# Having issues with ordering in my sql statement

Tags: sql

I have the following sql statement that works great and all but the ordering isn't quite working the way I was hoping.

```
SELECT article_type as search
FROM appendix_article_type 
WHERE article_type LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN article_type like '".$keyword." %' THEN 0 
WHEN article_type like '".$keyword."%' THEN 1 
WHEN article_type like '% ".$keyword."%' THEN 2 
ELSE 3 END, article_type
```

When I type the letter V it renders out the following in this order:

```
//search
Volleyball - Sand
Scenic Views
Vacation Rentals
Volleyball - Indoor
Online - Delivery
Snorkeling & Diving
```

I want it to be like this

```
//search
Vacation Rentals
Volleyball - Indoor
Volleyball - Sand
Scenic Views
Online - Delivery
Snorkeling & Diving
```

UPDATE / EDIT:

I kind have figured out my problem. I have a union attached to it that I think is causing the problems. If i removed the union it worked fine.

```
(SELECT article_type as search, "Article Type" as search_type, "article-type" as search_page 
FROM appendix_article_type 
WHERE article_type LIKE '%v%' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN article_type like 'v %' THEN 0 
WHEN article_type like 'v%' THEN 1 
WHEN article_type like '% v%' THEN 2 
ELSE 3 END, article_type)
UNION (
     SELECT DISTINCT(article_title) as search, "Article" as search_type, article_type_page as search_page 
     FROM system_article 
     INNER JOIN appendix_article_type ON system_article.article_type_id = appendix_article_type.article_type_id 
     WHERE article_status = '1' 
     AND article_title LIKE '%v%' 
     ORDER BY CASE WHEN article_title like 'v %' THEN 0 
     WHEN article_title like 'v%' THEN 1 
     WHEN article_title like '% v%' THEN 2 
     ELSE 3 END, article_title
)
```

Comment: Remove case and do order by article_type

Answer (score 1):

It works here:

```
drop table if exists appendix_article_type;
create table appendix_article_type (article_type text);
insert into appendix_article_type values 
('Volleyball - Sand'),
('Scenic Views'),
('Vacation Rentals'),
('Volleyball - Indoor'),
('Online - Delivery'),
('Snorkeling & Diving');


SELECT article_type as search
FROM appendix_article_type 
WHERE upper(article_type) LIKE '%V%' 
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN upper(article_type) like 'V %' THEN 0 
WHEN upper(article_type) like 'V%' THEN 1 
WHEN upper(article_type) like '% V%' THEN 2 
ELSE 3 END, article_type;
```

Results:

```
"Vacation Rentals"
"Volleyball - Indoor"
"Volleyball - Sand"
"Scenic Views"
"Online - Delivery"
"Snorkeling & Diving"
```

**Update:**

You have to do your "order by" outside the "union"

```
SELECT *
FROM
(       

  SELECT article_type as search, "Article Type" as search_type, "article-type" as search_page 
  FROM appendix_article_type 
  WHERE article_type LIKE '%v%' 

  UNION 

  SELECT article_title as search, "Article" as search_type, article_type_page as search_page 
  FROM system_article 
  INNER JOIN appendix_article_type ON system_article.article_type_id = appendix_article_type.article_type_id 
  WHERE article_status = '1' 
  AND article_title LIKE '%v%' 


) A

ORDER BY 
     CASE WHEN search like 'v %' THEN 0 
          WHEN search like 'v%' THEN 1 
          WHEN search like '% v%' THEN 2 
          ELSE 3 
     END, 
     search
```

Comment: I found the "problem" but need help with a solution if you're willing to look at my update.